# Slow mktime when parsing 100,000 YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS strings in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, mktime

I have 100,000 std::strings in the form YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS, eg. "20160621.213500" which I need to parse and populate a structure with some values, including an epoch timestamp.

It runs very slowly and the culprit is the call to mktime.  Any alternative to speed this up?

```
#define STRNCPY(dest, src, len) \
    { memcpy((dest), (src), (len)) ; dest[(len)] = '\0'; }

void
DvStorUtils::parseDateTimeString(const char *dateTimeStr, TDateTime &dateTime)
{
    // New, C-Style implementation
    strcpy(dateTime.dateTimeStr, dateTimeStr);

    char buf[32];
    STRNCPY(buf, dateTimeStr,    4);  dateTime.year   = atoi(buf);
    STRNCPY(buf, dateTimeStr+ 4, 2);  dateTime.month  = atoi(buf);
    STRNCPY(buf, dateTimeStr+ 6, 2);  dateTime.day    = atoi(buf);
    STRNCPY(buf, dateTimeStr+ 9, 2);  dateTime.hour   = atoi(buf);
    STRNCPY(buf, dateTimeStr+11, 2);  dateTime.minute = atoi(buf);
    STRNCPY(buf, dateTimeStr+13, 2);  dateTime.second = atoi(buf);


    struct tm tmStruct;
    tmStruct.tm_year = dateTime.year - 1900;
    tmStruct.tm_mon  = dateTime.month-1;
    tmStruct.tm_mday = dateTime.day;
    tmStruct.tm_hour = dateTime.hour;
    tmStruct.tm_min  = dateTime.minute;
    tmStruct.tm_sec  = dateTime.second;

    dateTime.totalSecElapsed = mktime(&tmStruct);
}
```

Comment: This blog post might be of interest:  https://gmbabar.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/mktime-slow-use-custom-function/

Comment: How slow is slow? What portion of the whole function is the `mktime()` call?

Comment: Maybe you could split the workload between threads?

Comment: Create you own `atoi` function like `uint16_t my_atoi(char *str, uin8_t digits)`

Comment: if your getting that 100000 strings from a file or other I/O, then the I/O time is swamping any time this function takes.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote.  Comment out mktime and it runs instantly (even printing to console each file name).  Put mktime in and takes 60 seconds. Jeremy had the right idea.  See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremy had the right idea – mktime is very very slow.

Comment out mktime and 100,000 lines are processed in an instant. Even when printing out each line.  Put it back in and takes almost a minute to complete.

I replaced mktime with the caching implementation [libfast-mktime](https://github.com/mnp/libfast-mktime/blob/master/fast-mktime.c) and it is almost as fast as without mktime at all.

The memoized `libfast-mktime` works well here because each line is very close in time to the ones before it.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up this mktime function it's enough to set up TZ system value like that:

- env TZ=PST8PDT
- export TZ=PST8PDT

And it'll work fast because escape each time get time zone

Answer (score -1):

If you want only time_t value from tm struct, then you can write a custom function for it. The additional time is maybe due to the fact that mktime also fills in the value of tm_wday and tm_yday, which is not used by your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).